# sql profiler 2008 does not accept template name in command line launch

Tags: sql-server, command-line, profiler, launch

I am trying to launch sql profiler 2008 from the command line launch. the syntax I used :

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn>profiler90 /S *server*
/D *dbname* /U sa /P *password* /T "C:\Documents and Settings\template.tdf"

actual result:
profiler opens, successful login happens but still I am forced to select a template.

Expected result:
is there any other command line parameter I need to use to force profiler to take up a specified template.

Edit:

GBN: Thanks for the suggestions.

I did the following changes profiler90 changed to profiler modified the template path to : C:\Documents and Settings\myuser\Application Data\Microsoft\SQL Profiler\10.0\Templates\Microsoft SQL Server\100**templatename**

the physical folder specified above contains the template file.

still the problem persists

Answer (score 2):

yes, it worked
the correct one is /t "template name" and not the physical file name of the template.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's "[profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162808.aspx)" in SQL Server 2008, "[profiler90](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162808(SQL.90).aspx)" in SQL Server 2005

The /T switch for both says

> ... The
>   template name must be in either the
>   system template directory or the user
>   template directory. If two templates
>   with the same name exist in both
>   directories, the template from the
>   system directory will be loaded. If no
>   template with the specified name
>   exists, the standard template will be
>   loaded. Note that the file extension for the template (.tdf) should not be specified as part of the template_name.

So, it looks like your switch is wrong because of the path and the extension.

Edit:

Have you tried just the name?: `.../T "templatename"...`

Answer (score 0):

GBN: Thanks for the suggestions.

I did the following changes profiler90 changed to profiler modified the template path to : C:\Documents and Settings\myuser\Application Data\Microsoft\SQL Profiler\10.0\Templates\Microsoft SQL Server\100**templatename**

the physical folder specified above contains the template file.

still the problem persists